# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Моя должность была эксперт по СЕИР.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать и так, как здесь сказано, а лучше сказать так: "Я занимал должность эксперта по СЕИР (нужна расшифровка)

Answer (score 0):

"Моя должность была эксперт по СЕИР".

Думаю, что предложение оформлено неправильно, желательно: "Моя должность была - эксперт по СЕИР".  В устной речи делается пауза, которая обозначается тире. Сравнить: "Моя должность - эксперт по СЕИР".

А то кажется, что должность была экспертом.

Comment: София, если б должность была экспертом, то так бы и написали в творительном падеже. Я считаю, что тире нужно только в настоящем времени, именно потому, что опускается сказуемое "есть".
Формально: Моя должность есть эксперт по СЕИР. А в прошедшем времени сказуемое на месте. (имхо)

Comment: В подобных случаях может использоваться как именительный, так и творительный падеж, например: "Мой дед был живописец/живописцем", причем И.п. обозначает постоянный признак. Можно сказать: Я был эксперт/экспертом по СЕИР, именно поэтому приведенное предложение мне кажется сомнительным.

Comment: Вопрос: Какая у тебя была должность? Ответ: У меня была должность эксперт по СЕИР. Вопрос: Как называлась твоя должность? Моя должность называлась эксперт по СЕИР. Никто не спросит "Какой была твоя должность?". Предложение действительно некорректно.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "была" вообще здесь неуместно. Правильно так, как написал Виктор.

Comment: "Я занимал должность эксперта по СЕИР" - нейтральный стиль, похожий на канцелярский. Нельзя разговорную речь заменять другой только потому, что это сложно записать (надо думать над грамматикой), а слово "была" как раз и придает сообщению свободный, разговорный характер.